# Where are variables stored if I once execute them in match function in Python?

Tags: python

So, the problem is that if I execute the code, and in an execution the match is only 'show', I've got an error: "todos[]" is not defined.

While, if i execute the same code, matching first, 'add' block and then 'show' block i don't have any error anymore. As I understood is because the Python defines "todos[]" in first block matching 'add'. But where is this variable stored?

Meaning, how case 'show' can see case 'add' even they are two different blocks.

```
while True:
user_action = input("Type add, show, edit, complete or exit: ").strip().lower()

match user_action:
    case 'add':
        todo = input("Enter a todo: ") + "\n"

        file = open('todos.txt', 'r')
        todos = file.readlines()
        file.close()

        todos.append(todo)

        file = open('todos.txt', 'w')
        file.writelines(todos)
        file.close()
    case 'show' | 'display':
        for index, item in enumerate(todos):
            print(f"{index+1}-{item}")
    case 'edit':
        number = int(input("Number of the todo to edit: "))
        number = number - 1
        new_todo = input("Enter new todo: ")
        todos[number] = newtodo.capitalize()
    case 'complete':
        number = int(input("Number of the todo to complete"))
        todos.pop(number - 1)
    case 'exit':
        break
    case :
        print("Hey, you entered an unknown command")
print("Bye!")
```

Comment: Todos is defined inside case one. Scope of the variable will not be available in show case.

Comment: If `todo` is created in the first pass through the loop it will be available in all cases in the next pass. You must have had a `show` case before an `add` case.

Comment: @VimalanE your comment doesn't really make sense. Scope isn't the issue here. Both cases are in the same scope.

Comment: Assign None to *todos* **before** *match* then test for its validity when the case is either 'show' or 'display'. Clearly it makes no sense to try to show/display something that you don't have. Also, you can't *break* outside of a loop. There's no loop here so that will lead to a syntax error

Comment: It doesn't look like reading from `todos.txt` is really specific to the `add` action, rather you just assume that `add` will happened first. Initialize `todos` from the file *before* the loop, so that the list is ready to show and/or modify once the loop begins. (And write the final list back to the file *after* the loop.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does not have block-scope. Only a handful of constructs create a new scope (like functions and list comprehensions). Loops and `match` statements do not create a new scope. They are a part of whatever outer scope they reside in.

When the 'add' block is entered, it assigns a value to the `todo` variable in the module scope (assuming this code isn't in a function). It's then still in scope when the `match` is entered again.

---

You should not write code like this though. Allowing variables to exist conditionally makes code harder to understand and more fragile.